# Can I replace my power adapter of external hard drive with this one?

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply

I have a removable hard drive. Its power adapter's specification is

```
Flying Electronic factory
model: FLY36-5-12
S/N: W0408182331
input:100-240 Vac,2A,50/60 Hz
output: 5V 1.5A, 12V 1.5A
```

I found that the light on the adapter isn't lit upt when plug into the wall electricity outlet. I have used it for 7 years. So I guess it is dead?

I search on the internet. The closest to my adapter is [this one](http://www.powerpayless.com/external-hard-drive-ac-dc-power-adapter-fly36-5-12-equiv.html)

```
External Hard Drive AC / DC power adapter FLY36-5-12 (equiv)    
Input voltage: 100V ~ 240V
Output: 12V, 5 V 2A Up to Up to Watts
```

If I understand correctly, the two adapters have the same specifications, except that the outputs of the two adpaters are not the same (1.5 A versus 2A). So I wonder if I can purchase the second one to replace the first one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the connectors are the same size and you should be ok. The ampage difference isn't too different... Can't promise anything though!

Most manufacturors will allow a slight difference, it's always safer to 'undervolt' and see if things work rather than supplying over, but that difference is only marginal.

Comment: Thanks! So overvolt is bad while overcurrent isn't?

Comment: There will be no overcurrent, because the supply will provide only the current your device will need and nothing more :-)

Answer (score 2):

Current output is actually "MAX CURRENT OUTPUT". If your appliance needs 1.5A at 12V, you can use a 200A 12V supply without problems (provided that connector and polarity matches)

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the adapter will be able to output any current that is less than the  "MAX CURRENT OUTPUT", depending on the my appliance's need?

Comment: Yes, precisely.